# Tomcat spiking and consuming all available CPU

Tags: performance, tomcat, cpu-usage, tomcat8, profiler

Tomcat (8.0.14-1+deb8u1) in production server suddenly hogs all CPU, what could be done to diagnose the cause? I'm aware that a profiler might come in handy, but not in a production environment, any ideas?

Additional information:
 ["top" command execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wwMi.png) / [lsb_release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5euG.png)

Comment: Memory / jmap output at: http://pastebin.com/UVJzfn1u

Comment: Threads / jstack output at http://pastebin.com/282hfyvv

Comment: JVM: java version "1.7.0_91"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.3) (7u91-2.6.3-1~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.91-b01, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gonzalo I've seen you've provided almost all necesary information, but I'll write my answer from the "beginning", so it can be helpfull for less experienced users who stumble upon it.

1. You should take a thread dump. You can do that by either:

   - kill -3 PID
   - jstack -F PID
2. Take a look at `top` or `htop` command output.

   - For `top` press "shift + h" to show the threads (You can also start top with `top -p PID` to filter out the irrelevant processes)
   - Find which thread consumes the CPU and write down the thread ID
   - The thread ID is in decimal, so you have to convert it to hexadecimal.
3. Open the thread dump and look for the hexadecimal thread it. This is the thread that consumes the CPU

PS: Your thread dump looks really strange and it misses the thread IDs. The thread stacks should start like :

```
"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 tid=0x02b3d000 nid=0x898 in Object.wait() [0x02d0f000]
...stack traces here...
```

where the `nid` is the thread id hexadecimal you found from top/htop.

Try taking the dump with `kill -3`

Comment: Added as comment in the question JVM version, just in case it does matter.

Comment: Tried getting a heap dump with kill -3 but didn't work, jstack worked, buy only with PID from 'ps' not the one from a thread (via top + shift-h)

Comment: You should take the dump with the PID of the JVM process, not the thread. You need teh thread id, to find which stacktrace corresponds to the CPU usage

Comment: Top output at: http://picpaste.com/Captura_de_pantalla_2016-03-02_a_las_2.13.21_p.m.-L7LsZq3X.png

Comment: @GonzaloVasquez so these are the faulty threads http://pastebin.com/BGvfqGQZ . It seems that the issue is in one of those methods: `InsertMovilProcess` or `InsertMovilCliente` or `UpdateMovilCache`. But without a source code and a debugger I cant tell what exactly is the issue, but still it;s a good starting point to investigate further

Comment: Thanks @Svetlin we'll try to debug those methods.

Comment: Possible offending Java code (but can't realize what the problem would be) at: http://pastebin.com/1CaV2i5z

Answer (score 0):

we are having the same issue on a couple of our servers. the problem also arises on tomcat servers without web apps, just serving static pages.  cpu usage suddenly spins to 200% and never comes down

this issue never appeared before our recent upgrade to 8.0.14 and 8_u_121

setup as follows:

- debian 8.1, latest patches
- tomcat 8.0.14
- oracle jvm 8_u_121  (latest as of this date)
- ram of 2,4 and 8 GBs (depending on servers)
- http/1.1 connector on 80 redirected to 443; nio1 connector on 443 with https (actually on 8080 and 8443, firewall maps 80 to 8080 and 443 to 8443)

when the problem occurs the symptoms are as follows:

- cpu usage 200% by process "java", doesn't come down
- ram consumption normal
- no log entry in apps.log
- about 20 entries in catalina.out as follows:

> 30-Jan-2017 10:15:38.479 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-16]
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing
>   HTTP request header  Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing
>   errors will be logged at DEBUG level. 30-Jan-2017 10:15:40.022 INFO
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-17]
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing
>   HTTP request header  Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing
>   errors will be logged at DEBUG level. 30-Jan-2017 10:15:41.574 INFO
>   [http-nio-8080-exec-18]
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing
>   HTTP request header

we had similar error messages in catalina.out when we upgraded to 8.0.14. It was because this release no longer accepted unescaped { and } in url. We fixed it by changing our client code to encode these characters into %4B and %4D. There was no cpu issue at the time